# Origen: Problems with flow branching using test ids

Tags: origen-sdk

I'm having some trouble with conditional flow branching based on the result of a previous test.  This flow code is intended generate a fall-back test point if the first test fails:

```
  bist :cpu, ip: :L2, testmode: :speed, cond: :pmin, id: :cpu_pmin
  bist :cpu, ip: :L2, testmode: :speed, cond: :pmax, if_failed: :cpu_pmin
```

Using origen to render the flow with this code generates two consecutive tests with no branching:

```
  run(cpu_L2_speed_pmin_95CE6EC);
  run(cpu_L2_speed_pmax_95CE6EC);
```

This does appear to work correctly when I use an id attached to a group, but not an individual test.

If I replace the second test call with a call to bin instead, I get an error:

```
  bist :cpu, ip: :L2, testmode: :speed, cond: :pmin, id: :cpu_pmin
  bin 10, if_failed: :cpu_pmin
```

produces the error message:

```
[ERROR]      1.464[0.927]    || Test ID cpu_pmin is referenced in flow func in the following lines, but it is never defined:
[ERROR]      1.465[0.000]    ||   /<origen_pathname>/program/func.rb:41
```

Comment: [Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131419/passing-params-to-v93k-test-suites-add-method) as I wasn't able to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure your bist method in the interface is not passing the options along when it is generating the flow entry.

You probably have something like:

```
flow.test(my_test_suite)
```

but you need to let the flow generator know about the `:id`, `:if_failed` and any other flow control options which are in play. This will probably do it:

```
flow.test(my_test_suite, options)
```

If you were to take your interface method out of the equation for a minute and change to this, then you should see it working:

```
flow.test :cpu, ip: :L2, testmode: :speed, cond: :pmin, id: :cpu_pmin
flow.test :cpu, ip: :L2, testmode: :speed, cond: :pmax, if_failed: :cpu_pmin
```