# Passing params to V93K test_suites.add method

Tags: origen-sdk

This is in reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125450/origen-problems-with-flow-branching-using-test-ids).  I checked our test interface and we are only passing the V93k primary params to the test_suites.add method.

```rb
  V93K_PRIMARIES = [:lev_equ_set, :lev_spec_set, :timset, :tim_equ_set, :tim_spec_set, :seqlbl, :levset]
  primary_tm_params = {}.tap do |primary_hash|
    V93K_PRIMARIES.each do |param|
      primary_hash[param] = tm_params.delete(param) unless tm_params[param].nil?
    end
  end
  # Create the test suite
  t = test_suites.add(test_name, primary_tm_params)
  t.test_method = test_methods.amd93k.send(options[:tm].to_sym, tm_params)
  V93K_PRIMARIES.each do |primary|
    t.send("#{primary}=", primary_tm_params[primary]) unless primary_tm_params[primary].nil?
  end
  # Insert the test into the flow
  test(t, tm_params)
```

When I set a breakpoint, I do see they were missing.  Here they are after updating the code:

```rb
 :ip=>:L2,
 :testmode=>:speed,
 :cond=>:pmax,
 :if_failed=>:cpu_pmin,
 :testtype=>:cpu,
 :test_ip=>:bist,
 :tm=>"Bist"}
```

And here is the .tf file generated from the original two tests in the original question:

```
      run_and_branch(cpu_L2_speed_pmin_965EA18)
      then
      {
      }
      else
      {
        @CPU_PMIN_965EA18_FAILED = 1;
      }
      if @CPU_PMIN_965EA18_FAILED == 1 then
      {
        run(cpu_L2_speed_pmax_965EA18);
      }
      else
      {
      }
```

I think we have it figured out, thx very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal approach to this is just to pass everything to `flow.test`, rather than a subset of the options passed from the flow.

It will only act on the options it recognizes, which are basically the flow control parameters (:id, :if_failed, :unless_enabled, etc) and the test and bin number parameters, and it will just ignore the rest.